# Compare two key of mongodb document if third key is true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document like this, I'm using mongo 3.6 and aggregation.

```
[
   {
      id: 123,
      isLimit: "YES",
      maxUserCanComment: 10,
      commentCount: 6 
   },
   {
      id: 124,
      isLimit: "NO",
      maxUserCanComment: 0,
      commentCount: 3 
   },
   {
      id: 125,
      isLimit: "YES",
      maxUserCanComment: 3,
      commentCount: 5 
   }
]
```

I need the document that document, if isLimit == "NO" take it and if isLimit == "YES", first check commentCount < maxUserCanComment. I tried this

```
[
   $expr: { $gt: ["$commentCount", "$maxUserCanComment"] } // and also tried to add ithis in $cond
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query operator here then you can use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) inside it.

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    { "isLimit": "NO" },
    {
      "isLimit": "YES",
      "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
          "$commentCount",
          "$maxUserCanComment"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fdSq-lRVvRb)